# Do you work with the react native should learn react.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

Everywhere is talking about react native and  react.js Now I want to know whether to work with react native must learn to react or react native of separate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it is advised to learn React before you start with React Native, since the principles you'll need when developing in React Native are all based on React.

From Facebook:

> React Native enables you to build world-class application experiences on native platforms using a consistent developer experience based on JavaScript and *React*.

So before you study all the mobile specific API's and attention points, it's good to be familiar with React itself.

Comment: Do you really build a strong program with react native؟

Comment: Depends on your specific use case, overall I'd say yes it is possible!

Comment: @MohNj One of the advantages of using RN is having one codebase that can run Android and iOS.

Answer (score 6):

That would depend on what you would like to do. Both are open sourced by Facebook:

[ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/): This is basically a ***JavaScript library*** used mainly as the V in MVC. But it can also render on the server side using Node. It can power user interfaces, web applications and native apps using React Native.

[React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/): This is a ***mobile framework*** that enables you to build native mobile applications using a consistent developer experience based on JavaScript and React.